# Is it possible to pass Bash commands from a Discord bot into a server's bash input?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am an amateur Python scripter and Linux user, so please bare with me. I have made simple Discord bots in the past.

I have a personal project where I want to simulate a Unix-like terminal in a discord channel, i.e. if I type 'ls', the discord bot will respond with the typical terminal output, a list of files.  The intent is to use this bot for a realtime RPG game I am planning, and I think Discord would be a great prop.  I intend to write the bot in Python, as I do not know javascript.

Can anyone comment on if this is possible, and if there would be any major pitfalls I should be aware of?

Follow-up question, should this be run in a Docker container to avoid destroying my AWS server?

Answer (score 0):

You could try os.system()

Start by importing the os module:

```
import os
```

and you could try:

```
bot.command()
async def run(ctx, arg1)
ctx.send(os.system(arg1))
```